# Github Actions - enforce rule on all submodules

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to enforce a rule using Github actions: on every push to the repo, the commit is checked for the existence of a README.md in each subrepo, otherwise failure. In the example below, this should fail.

```
my_repo
│
├ sub_repo1
│   ├ README.md
│   └ other files...
│
└ sub_repo2
    └ other files...
```

I've tried using the action `andstor/file-existence-action@v2`, and this comes close but in the above example, it would pass the test because the glob pattern checks for **any** submodule meeting the criteria, and I need **all** submodules:

```
name: check-for-readme
run-name: Checking ${{ github.event.head_commit.author.name }}'s push for readme
on: [push]
jobs:
  check-for-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "${{ toJson(github) }}"

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Check file existence
        id: check_files
        uses: andstor/file-existence-action@v2
        with:
          files: "*/README.md"
          fail: true

      - name: Action on failure
      - ...
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a Bash script and use the counts of the subrepos and their README files like this:

`check.bash`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

repo_count=$(find . ! -path . -type d -maxdepth 1 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
readme_count=$(find . -type f -name 'README.md' -maxdepth 2 2>/dev/null | wc -l)

status="success"
if (( repo_count != readme_count )); then
  status="failure"
fi

echo "status=$status" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

Make sure to make this executable before pushing it to your repo:

```bash
chmod +x check.bash
```

Assuming that this script is located on the root of your repo, it can be used similar to your existing steps:

```yaml
      - name: Check file existence
        id: check_files
        run: ./check.bash

      - name: Action on failure
        if: ${{ steps.check_files.outputs.status == 'failure' }}
        run: echo "do something here..."
```

Depending on your use case, you may further refine it accordingly.

Comment: Had to fiddle around with arguments for `find` to get exactly what I wanted, but got it working. Thanks!